# std::thread delay alternatives in c++

Tags: c++

I need a function to sleep before sending packet to server, but not sleeping the whole app.
I figured I can use threads like this:

```
void SendPunch(TankPacket data) {
    while (gt::onauto) {
        if (!gt::placed) {
            if (gt::automagplant) {
                data.MainValue = 5640;
            } else {
                data.MainValue = gt::itemid;
            }
            g_server->send(false, NET_MESSAGE_GAME_PACKET, g_server->PackForSendingRaw(&data), sizeof data, nullptr);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(166));
            gt::placed = true;
        }
        if (gt::placed) {
            data.MainValue = 18;
            g_server->send(false, NET_MESSAGE_GAME_PACKET, g_server->PackForSendingRaw(&data), sizeof data, nullptr);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(166));
        }
    }
}

void ThreadFunction() {
        auto& me = g_server->m_world.local;
        TankPacket data{};
        data.PacketType = 3;
        data.NetID = me.netid;
        data.ExtDataMask = 16;
        data.X = me.pos.m_x;
        data.Y = me.pos.m_y;
        if (gt::autoright) {
            data.PunchX = me.pos.m_x / 32 + 1;
        } else if (gt::autoleft) {
            data.PunchX = me.pos.m_x / 32 - 1;
        } else {
            data.PunchX = me.pos.m_x / 32;
        }
        data.PunchY = me.pos.m_y / 32;
        auto* th = new std::jthread(SendPunch, data);
        th->detach();
}
```

the loop works for some time, then the whole program crashes. Possibly due to ENet not liking multi threads.

my attempt here was create thread, send the packet + delay, delete thread.

Is there a possibility to do something like this without threads?

Comment: A fixed thread pool and a priority queue will *probably* do what you need, and fix your blatant memory leak as a bonus. consider that instead.

Comment: Threading is the solution, but from this code, it's impossible to tell if you're repeatedly calling ThreadFunction. If you are, eventually you have a LOT of threads, and that can cause no end of trouble.

Comment: @JosephLarson im only calling it once, also when gt::placed is true and it sends the packet, there is code elsewhere to check and sets gt::placed to false, making it endless loop

Comment: "then the whole program crashes. Possibly due to ENet not liking multi threads." sounds like just a guess. What is the crash? Who is accessing the variables that `SendPunch` access (like `g_server`)?

Comment: I'm going to ask as slightly different question of you... "Why?" The reason I ask is because a common reason for sleeping is "oh... the next thing happened fast and so didn't work, but everything works if I sleep". Usually sleep is an anti-pattern to solving the actual problem and if you can explain what makes you think the sleep is necessary, people may be able to suggest much better answers.

Comment: @Charlie sleep is needed, between sending the packets, else the server won't accept it at all, when no delay.

Comment: @MargaritaWeiß that's ... usually not a problem with the server. A common cause is that something goes immediately from sending a packet to trying to read the response, and no response is there yet so you get nothing. The right solution is to use something like select/epoll/ or something like asio network libraries to read the socket after the response has come back. Sleep is an anti-pattern in this case.